# Jquery ignores if-statement when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've written a function which makes my top-bar (`$header`) fixed if you scroll down on device ( `< 992` ) which works fine. And when I resize, I use the function `fixedTopCheck()` again and it removes the `.fixed` class (in the else statement). This also works fine. But then when I scroll, it suddendly gives top the class `.fixed` again. So this part is getting ignored `if ($(window).width() < 992)` (which only happens when resizing, if I refresh with a window above 992px it works fine).

So is this resizing messing with the recognition of `$(window).width()`? (When I console log it, it shows the correct width size).

My code:

```
$(function()
{
    var $header = $('header.top');

    var $input = $header.find('input[type=search]');
    var $search = $header.find('div.search');
    var $container = $('main#content');
    var $searchBtn = $search.find('button.icon-search');
    var $closeBtn = $search.find('span.icon-cross');

    $closeBtn.css('display', 'none');


    function fixedTopCheck()
    {
        if ($(window).width() < 992)
        {
            $(window).on('scroll', function()
            {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 75)
                {
                    $searchBtn.css('display', 'inline-block');
                    $closeBtn.css('display', 'none');

                    // Turn top into fixed menu
                    $header.addClass('fixed');
                    $container.addClass('fixed');
                    // Hide search bar and make it smaller
                    $input.css('display', 'none');

                    // Prevent search button to search
                    $searchBtn.on('click', function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();
                    });


                    // Open search bar when clicking button
                    $(document).on('click','.icon-search',function()
                    {
                        $searchBtn.unbind('click');
                        $input.css('display', 'inline-block');
                        $searchBtn.css('display', 'none');
                        $closeBtn.css('display', 'inline-block');

                        $input.focus();
                    });

                    // Close search bar when clicking button
                    $(document).on('click','.icon-cross',function()
                    {
                        $searchBtn.on('click', function(e)
                        {
                            e.preventDefault();
                        });

                        $input.css('display', 'none');
                        $searchBtn.css('display', 'inline-block');
                        $closeBtn.css('display', 'none');
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    // Reverse fixed menu
                    $header.removeClass('fixed');
                    $container.removeClass("fixed");

                    $input.css('display', 'inline-block');

                    // Return search function
                    $searchBtn.unbind('click');

                    // Reset search form when going top and search form is still opened
                    $searchBtn.css('display', 'inline-block');
                    $closeBtn.css('display', 'none');
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("hello");
            // Remove fixed top
            if($header.hasClass("fixed"))
            {
                $header.removeClass("fixed");
            }

            if($container.hasClass("fixed"))
            {
                $container.removeClass("fixed");
            }

            $searchBtn.css('display', 'inline-block');
            $closeBtn.css('display', 'none');
        }
    }

    fixedTopCheck();

    // if window is resized check again
    $( window ).resize(function() {
        fixedTopCheck();
    });
});
```

Comment: On each resize, you are binding new scroll event which bind new click events, etc... Don't nest events

Comment: Thank you. You are correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is following **a lot** of bad practices.

1. dont nest your event listeners inside each other. this will cause setting an event listener on the same component everytime its container event triggers (on each resize is VERY heavy aswell).
2. instead of using bind and unbind, make a check the width inside each event and follow actions depending on that.
3. another solution for replacing bind and unbind in your case is to keep the default button events, but disable the button so it cannot be clicked instead of unbind.

This will answer your question:

4. adding events inside resize, will not make them only work on that size in the if statement, you have to put the event outside the resize event and check whenever that event happens on the scroll and size.

Comment: Thanks, great explanation

Answer (score 0):

When the page is loaded and the width of the page is <992px, the scroll event is created. When you resize to >992px the scroll event will still exist.
I would recommend binding the scroll event only once on page load (not after each resize) and check the width inside of that method to decide what it should do when it's scrolling.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.